Separar enlaces (Link a) dentro de un Div
¿Qué tal estáis?
Estoy intentando algo que pensé que sería simple, pero no logro entender el procedimiento que realiza HTML y CSS.
Estoy intentando colocar un enlace de "Anterior" en el lado izquierdo y un enlace de "Siguiente" en el extremo derecho de un DIV. Pero si uso margin no responde como quiero, si intento ponerlo de forma relativa y usar sus herramientas (left, right, top, bottom) no me hace caso. Creo que debe ser que el texto tiene su propia propiedad de tamaño que entra en juego evitando el desplazamiento.
Se que los enlaces tienen una propiedad inline, lo que hace que se alineen a la izquierda, pero no logro separar el segundo hasta el extremo derecho y que respete ese extremo.


div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  min-width: 665px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a#izq {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

a#der {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    </head>
    <body>        
        
        <div style="">
                <a id="izq" href="">Anterior</a>
                <a id="der" href="">Siguiente</a>                
            
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>



Se que debe ser algo sencillo, pero no doy con la clave.
Desde ya muchísimas gracias a todos.

Tal vez te sirva esto:


div { 
   display: flex;
}

a#izq { 
   display: flex; justify-content: left; width: 100%;
}

a#der { 
   display: flex; justify-content: right; width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    </head>
    <body>        
        
        <div style="">
                <a id="izq" href="">Anterior</a>
                <a id="der" href="">Siguiente</a>                              
        </div>            
        
    </body>
</html>




FlexBox, lo estoy utilizando en casi todo el proyecto y no se me ocurrió usarlo en este momento. Tienes razón, es la mejor forma de posicionamiento. Muchísimas gracias.

Un placer maestro!!!.

Puedes usar la propiedad "float" para lograr el efecto deseado:


div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  min-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a#izq {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
}

a#der {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  float:right;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    </head>
    <body>        
        
        <div style="">
                <a id="izq" href="">Anterior</a>
                <a id="der" href="">Siguiente</a>                
            
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>



Como también puedes usar flexbox y decirle al contenedor padre que tenga display:flex y justify-content: space-between.


div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  min-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a#izq {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

a#der {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div style="">
    <a id="izq" href="">Anterior</a>
    <a id="der" href="">Siguiente</a>

  </div>


</body>

</html>




Muchas gracias, probaré las dos opciones. Con el float me daba problemas, pero lo plantearé como me lo comentas.
